# How to capture a string without quote characters

Tags: parsing, f#, lexical-analysis, fsyacc, fslex

I'm trying to capture quoted strings without the quotes. I have this terminal

```
%token <string> STRING
```

and this production

```
constant:
    | QUOTE STRING QUOTE { String($2) }
```

along with these lexer rules

```
| '\''       { QUOTE }
| [^ '\'']*  { STRING (lexeme lexbuf) } //final regex before eof
```

It seems to be interpreting everything leading up to a `QUOTE` as a single lexeme, which doesn't parse. So maybe my problem is elsewhere in the grammar--not sure. Am I going about this the right way? It was parsing fine before I tried to exclude quotes from strings.

#### Update

I think there may be some ambiguity with the following lexer rules

```
let name = alpha (alpha | digit | '_')*
let identifier = name ('.' name)*
```

The following rule is prior to `STRING`

```
| identifier    { ID (lexeme lexbuf) }
```

Is there any way to disambiguate these without including quotes in the `STRING` regex?

Comment: Why don't you want to include quotes in the `STRING` regex? The ambiguity you note between `ID` and `STRING` is deep, why would you want two similar terminals like that?

Comment: Obviously quotes aren't part of string literals themselves, but stripping them out in the parser is easy enough. You're right that removing them from the regex introduces too much ambiguity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty normal to do semantic analysis in the lexer for constants like strings and numeric literals, so you might consider a lex rule for your string constants like

```
| '\'' [^ '\'']* '\'' 
    { STRING (let s = lexeme lexbuf in s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2)) }
```

Comment: This is equivalent to trimmming the quotes, no?

Comment: Correct - the key difference from @Vitaliy's answer is that I'm doing the stripping in the lexer rather than the parser (which means if you want to use the `STRING` terminal other places in your parser, you don't have to trim it at each spot).

Comment: Ah, yes...that's an important difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lexeme with quotes, but trim quotes in parser

*Lexer:*

```
let constant       = ("'" ([^ '\''])* "'")
...
| constant         { STRING(lexeme lexbuf) }
```

*Parser:*

```
%token <string> STRING

...
constant:
    | STRING { ($1).Trim([|'''|]) }
```

**Or** if you want to extract quotes from string:

*Lexer:*

```
let name = alpha (alpha | digit | '_')*
let identifier = name ('.' name)*
...

| '\''       { QUOTE }
| identifier { ID (lexeme lexbuf) }
| _          { STRING (lexeme lexbuf) }
```

*identifier* will take away symbols from STRING, so 
your lexeme stream can be like: *QUOTE ID STRING ID .. QUOTE*, and you have to handle this in parser:

*Parser:*

```
constant:
     | QUOTE content QUOTE     { String($2) }

content:
     | ID content      { $1+$2 }
     | STRING content  { $1+$2 }
     | ID              { $1 }
     | STRING          { $1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I capture them in the "lexic.l" file using states.
[Here my autoanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21041016/1430554)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer